# Flutter shows blank screen on chrome

Tags: flutter

so I'm developing a web application using Flutter.
when I want to see run and debug I see blank screen!
the output is on chrome but it's like chrome opens for the very first time like this:
[image]

I can see the output if I open chrome and search the url(in this example(`localhost:42827`)

I tried answers of other questions but those didn't help
by the way I'm using `intellij idea` on `ubuntu`

[image]

and this is my `flutter doctor` result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go through the below steps mostly first step will solve your issue still check other if it dosen't

1. Try giving path as  `<base href="./">` in `index.js` in web folder
2. run your app using  `flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html`
3. run your app using  `flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer canvaskit`
4. if this doesn't work then add this line in index.js inside

```
<script>
     if (platform.name.toLowerCase() == "safari" && 
     parseInt(platform.version.split(".")[0]) >= 15) {
           window.flutterWebRenderer = "html";
            } else { 
              window.flutterWebRenderer = "canvaskit";
            }
</script>
```

Comment: second solution works fine but i lost hot reload!